# Studies for personal finances

Tags: investing, canada, stock-markets, expense-tracking, financial-independence

Over the last couple of days, I started thinking about financial independence for myself.

That idea sounds great to me as I'm 33 years old, have a good and stable income, and I could do something to save my money. It's just time for me to think about saving.

My problem is lack of knowledge and experience of finances.

Concepts I've discovered so far:

1. Idea of early retirement.
2. Financial independence.
3. Combination of first two in F.I.R.E.

Those ideas looks simple on first view: track your money, spend less, invest more. But when I'm thinking about this, I'm getting more and more questions: what does 'money tracking' mean? What does that look like? Where and how can I invest money? There are should be strategies and common-sense approaches to do this.

I looked on stocks/options/futures/bonds/etf, etc., and got some basic ideas. That sounds more or less familiar for me as I worked in investment banking area before (as software developer). But I feel that this is a big picture and I don't see details on it.

My goal is to figure out a way to keep saving and start personal investing in nearest future. So this is about building my (and my family's) financial independence and potentially early retirement (if possible).

As I realizing that I have no knowledge about finances, so I cant rely on my own choice for places to study that.

What I think I need to learn so far:

1. How to track personal finances? What instruments applicable? What the common approaches to do so?
2. Tracking is not enough, I want to learn how to manage it, how to build short and long term plans and so one.
3. Apart of tracking and planning, I would like to learn accessible ways of investment. What options for investment me (or any other guy) have? How to choose type of investment which is fit to me?
4. I'm newcomer in Canada and I'm planning to stick here for long term, so I wonder about any Canada's specific options for my goals?

So I'm asking for particular books, courses, trainings and other learnings which could help to me. Not just bunch of links which I can google by myself, but best materials accessible. I believe there is should be pool of best learnings, "classic" books or well known courses or something like this.

If that sounds as off-topic then please just give a direction.

If direction is off-topic as well, I'm asking to give me at least some learning themes so I will figure out rest stuff by myself.

Comment: This is a very broad question, and also asks for specific course-type material recommendations, both of which can be reasons to close a question as being off-topic. To fully answer you would be hours and hours of discussion - If you narrow your question down to something concrete and specific, it may be answerable.

Comment: You might as well just start reading the financial best sellers and then discover what holds the attention. Otherwise a mortgage on a residence is an inflation hedge while buy-and-hold investment in equities is a tax shelter.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon as I explained, I don't have enough knowledge to ask specific questions. I would like to ask some concrete, but I'm not sure what is concrete. I'm looking for advice on learning path and study materials. How this could be more concrete?

Comment: @SSpring I came from totally different country and different environment. That's why when you mention "best sellers", I have no clue what you talking about. I can google for best sellers and get hundreds books, which making me just more confusing. This is a reason why I had to post this question. I want to filter all massive of information and read/learn only best possible books/sources/etc.

Comment: @tym32167 To start with, you should break this question down into just 1 of your 4 'things I think I need to learn so far'. Each question being smaller helps make it answerable. Post 4 questions, each smaller, each with a more specific request.

Comment: Don't google for "best sellers" but google for "financial best sellers". Also, look for adult-continuing-education classes offered by colleges and universities in the metro. Or here is a link to free online finance courses from MIT: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/find-by-topic/#cat=business&subcat=finance .

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon I thought that my questions coupled (like no point to investing if you not tracking your money) but if you saying that this is separate questions, I will split this and will ask them separately once I will be ready to do so. Thanks!

Comment: @SSpring sure, I meant "financial best sellers" as well. Thanks for link, I will check it out.

Comment: @tym32167 Yes they are connected, but together they form enough material a crash course on personal investing. Without focussing onto something more readily answerable, there isn't much there that isn't simply a request for general resources, which is off-topic for this site.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon hmm, that weird. I mean, I contributing into russian SO and we have special questions for general literature, like [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/454683/179763), so I hoped to see smthg similar. But now I got your point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised that no one has recommended that you read "The Intelligent Investor" by Graham.  That suggestion usually makes me laugh because it's not for noobs.  Be that as it may, opinions on how to invest and what to invest in are as plentiful as the day is long and what suits one person may not suit another.

The simplest advice that  I can offer is to read everything that you can about the financial markets. The starting point might be as basic as the "XYZ For Dummies" books.  Build a basic foundation first.  As you understand more, seek out more complex books in areas of the market that interest you (Equities? ETFs?  Closed end funds? Mutual Funds?  etc.)  As you understand more, you you will get an idea of what intrigues you.  At that point, you'll be able to judge a book by its cover (OK, maybe the Index) and determine for yourself if it's worth reading.

Understanding financial markets is like learning a foreign language. It takes time and effort, something most people don’t want to do and as a result of failing to do so, they often lose their money. Financial markets quickly take the money of the inexperienced and uninformed.

The short answer?  Get a library card and worry about "best sellers" later because they're likely  to  be over your  head now.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I briefly looked on `"The Intelligent Investor" by Graham` and see that this book is like couple of decades old. Is it still actual today? Im not pretending to become investment pro after reading this, Im pretending to know at least where to pay attention, to know topics which I need to learn, to know where to move forward.

Comment: I can't tell you if "The Intelligent Investor" is relevant to today because I have never read it. All I can say is that it's a common 'must read' recommendation on many financial web sites and blogs. When I was in college (1970's), there was a school teacher friend of my parents who was a self made millionaire from the stock market. I asked him about how to learn about the stock market and his advice was "Read, read, read." That advice served me well and not only did I get to retire young but my investments and trading pay for all retirement expenses and I'm barely drawing down my net worth.

Comment: Im happy for you and your friend that you have enough money to do what you like to do. As you saying this a good book to read, I will start from here. I dont have pink dreams to become reach after 1 day tradings, I know that this is complicated and I want to be more conservative in my path. Im kind of in very beginning of this way, so Im planing to learn first, then act. Thank you for your time.

Comment: As I asked for starting point and you gave that book to me, I have things to do. This is not fully answers to whole question, but I realized that question is too wide, so it not possible to have answer on everything. I will mark this as answer now but keeping right to change my mind in case of alternative questions in future.

Comment: Any answer is subjective ---> As I wrote, **Opinions on how to invest and what to invest in are as plentiful as the day is long and what suits one person may not suit another.** This applies to books and trading courses as well.

Comment: I realize that this is person/situation specific. But I can't say what is best thing for me without knowledge of finances. This looks like chicken-egg problem. That's why I asked for starting point as I want to learn this before I can say is it fit to me or not. Basically, instead of picking random book, I will start from book which is recommended by many ppl. I'm not going to market now, I'm going to learn first and understand strategies.